# Foreach dentro de otro foreach de días

Tags: php, array, bucles, foreach

Por favor su ayuda!

Tengo un array de días;

```
$dias = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

y un array de fechas de usuarios;

```
$fec_usuarios = array(
   1 => 'Alejandro',
   4 => 'David',
   9 => 'Mari'
 );
```

La idea es que me imprima la lista de días del 1 al 9, pero donde coincida con el array de fec_usuarios, debería imprimir el nombre del usuario.

Hasta el momento tengo esto;

```
foreach ($dias as $dia){    
 foreach($fec_usuarios as $fecha => $usuario){      
    if($dia == $fecha){
        echo $dia . '-' . $usuario . '<br>';
     } 
  }
}
```

Que da como resultado lo siguiente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que me muestre por ejemplo;

1-Alejandro
2-Sin registro
3-Sin registro
4-David
5-Sin registro
6-Sin registro
7-Sin registro
8-Sin registro
9-Mari

Agradecería algo de su ayuda!
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo lo haria con un solo foreach

```
 foreach ($dias as $dia){    
    if(isset($fec_usuarios[$dia])){
        echo "$dia . '-' . $fec_usuarios[$dia];
     } 
     else{
        echo $dia . '- Sin Registro';
     } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola encontré respuesta a la pregunta!

Mil gracias!

La respuesta sería;

```
foreach ($dias as $dia){
     if(array_key_exists($dia, $fec_usuarios)== false){
         echo $dia . ' - Sin registro<br>';
     }        
     foreach($fec_usuarios as $fecha => $usuario){      
         if($dia == $fecha){
             echo $dia . '-' . $usuario . '<br>';
         }         
     }
 }
```